# Prevent encoding of javascript assigned to onchange event of Html.TextBoxFor via htmlAttributes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Html.TextBoxFor which I would like to assign some dynamic javascript to (the onchange event specifically):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => answer.Value, new { @class = "answerinput", @onchange = "submitAnswer(\"" + Model.QuestionID.ToString() + "\")" });
```

However, when I examine the resulting HTML, the quotes around the value passed into the javascript function are encoded, which is a problem:

```
onchange="submitAnswer(&quot;3&quot;)"
```

I've tried a few things, like placing the string into an IHtmlString and then using the IHtmlString in the assignment but the results are always the same.

Is there a way to prevent MVC from encoding the value assigned to @onchange?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making it an MvcHtmlString? ex: `onchange = MvcHtmlString.Create("\"3\"")`

Comment: Sorry Tejs, same result (the quotes still get encoded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you should change the way you are attaching to the event:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty, new { rel = Model.QuestionID, @class = "SomeClass" });
```

Then in javascript, attach to the event:

```
$('.SomeClass').each(function()
{
     $(this).change(function()
     {
          var questionId = $(this).attr('rel');
     });
});
```

Comment: This works, although I'd still like to know how (if?) there is a way to stop Razor from encoding everything (I'm sure it will come up again :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507671/bootstrap-datepicker-change-date-event-doesnt-fire-up-when-manually-editing-date

Answer (score -1):

Try using single quotes, no escape character required.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => answer.Value, new { @class = "answerinput", @onchange = "submitAnswer('" + Model.QuestionID.ToString() + "')" });
```

Comment: Yes I gave that a shot, the results are similar (but with a different encoding for the single-quote character).