# bootstrap datepicker change date event doesnt fire up when manually editing dates or clearing date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // When the document is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            // do what you want here
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            if ($('#startdate').val() != '' && $('#enddate').val() != ''){
                $('#period').text(diffInDays() + ' d.'); 
            } else {
                $('#period').text("-");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So here's what my datepicker looks like. So basically when I change date by clicking mouse it works good, however when I manually change date with keyboard or manually clear the date change date event doesn't get called. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have to use the `change` event on the input itself if you want to respond to manual input, because the `changeDate` event is only for when the date is changed using the datepicker.

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    })
    //Listen for the change even on the input
    .change(dateChanged)
    .on('changeDate', dateChanged);
});

function dateChanged(ev) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
    if ($('#startdate').val() != '' && $('#enddate').val() != '') {
        $('#period').text(diffInDays() + ' d.');
    } else {
        $('#period').text("-");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example  ?

Comment: `.change(...).on('changeDate')` causing double firing.

Comment: Instead of 'changeDate' try 'dp.change' that worked for me

Comment: how to get month change event?

Comment: I have value for input datepicker e.g _08-16-2017_. When page is refreshed the value _08-16-2017_ is assigned to input field. Is it possible to trigger `changeDate` via code after assigning value.

Comment: I had to add a keydown event to check for the tab key in IE.  I found the delete and enter keys triggered the change, but the tab key did not.

Answer (score 8):

In version 2.1.5

- bootstrap-datetimepicker.js
- http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker
- Contributions:
- Andrew Rowls
- Thiago de Arruda
- updated for Bootstrap v3 by Jonathan Peterson @Eonasdan

changeDate has been renamed to change.dp so changedate was not working for me

```
$("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker().on('change.dp', function (e) {
            FillDate(new Date());
    });
```

also needed to change css class from datepicker to datepicker-input

```
<div id='datetimepicker' class='datepicker-input input-group controls'>
   <input id='txtStartDate' class='form-control' placeholder='Select datepicker' data-rule-required='true' data-format='MM-DD-YYYY' type='text' />
   <span class='input-group-addon'>
       <span class='icon-calendar' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Date formate also works in capitals like this data-format='MM-DD-YYYY'

it might be helpful for someone it gave me really hard time :)

Comment: As of version  4.7.14, the correct event reference is "dp.change"

Answer (score 7):

The new version has changed.. for the latest version use the code below:

```
$('#UpToDate').datetimepicker({
        format:'MMMM DD, YYYY',
        maxDate:moment(),
        defaultDate:moment()            
    }).on('dp.change',function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(".datepicker").on("dp.change", function(e) {
    alert('hey');
});
```

Comment: Also describe your solution, so it will be clear what and why you're trying to do in your code.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a short solution for it.
No extra code is needed just trigger the *changeDate* event. E.g.
`$('.datepicker').datepicker().trigger('changeDate');`

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code sample.it is working for me

```
var date_input_field = $('input[name="date"]');
    date_input_field .datepicker({
        dateFormat: '/dd/mm/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
    }).on('change', function(selected){
        alert("startDate..."+selected.timeStamp);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should make it work in both cases

```
function onDateChange() {
   // Do something here
}

$('#dpd1').bind('changeDate', onDateChange);
$('#dpd1').bind('input', onDateChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Depending which date picker for Bootstrap you're using, this is a known bug currently with this one:

Code: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

(Docs: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Here's a bug report:

https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1957

If anyone has a solution/workaround for this one, would be great if you'd include it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this version about datetimepicker https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/ and for any reason doesn`t work the change event with jquery but with JS vanilla  it does

I figure out like this

```
document.getElementById('date').onchange = function(){ ...the jquery code...}
```

I hope work for you

Answer (score 0):

I was using AngularJS and AngularStrap 2.3.7 and trying to catch the `'change'` event by listening to a `<form>` element (not the input itself) and none of the answers here worked for me.  I tried to do:

```
$(form).on('change change.dp dp.change changeDate' function () {...})
```

And nothing would fire.  I ended up listening to the `focus` and `blur` events and setting a custom property before/after on the element itself:

```
// special hack to make bs-datepickers fire change events
// use timeout to make sure they all exist first
$timeout(function () {  
    $('input[bs-datepicker]').on('focus', function (e){
        e.currentTarget.focusValue = e.currentTarget.value;
    });        
    $('input[bs-datepicker]').on('blur', function (e){
        if (e.currentTarget.focusValue !== e.currentTarget.value) {
            var event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
            e.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    });
})
```

This basically manually checks the value before and after the `focus` and `blur` and dispatches a new `'change'` event.  The `{ bubbles: true }` bit is what got the form to detect the change.  If you have any datepicker elements inside of an `ng-if` you'll need to wrap the listeners in a `$timeout` to make sure the digest happens first so all of your datepicker elements exist.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.single_datetime').length){
        $('.single_datetime').dateRangePicker({ format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm', language: 'tr', autoClose: true, singleDate : true, showShortcuts: false, time: {enabled: true}
        }).bind('datepicker-change',function(event,obj){caclDay();});
    }
```

Ref: https://www.chamonix-property.com/bower_components/jquery-date-range-picker/