# Bootstrap Date Paginator datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, pagination

I would like to make redirect when a date is changed and transmit selected date parameter (via window.location.href). I'm using Bootstrap Date Paginator, which contains Bootstrap datepicker, but I don't know how to change these lines of code to work properly:

```
this.$calendar
  .datepicker({
    options...
  })
  .datepicker('update', this.options.selectedDate.toDate())
  .on('changeDate', $.proxy(this._calendarSelect, this));
```

I know I would use changeDate event but there aren't any examples of using this event. Can you help me, please?

Comment: you want example for .on('changeDate', ...)??

Comment: Yes, example of using changeDate event. I tried to do it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

You can use `.on('change', ..)` like this,

```
this.$calendar
  .datepicker({
    options...
  }).on('change', function() {
       var changedDate = this.$calendar.val();
       //alert("value of date is "+ x);
    var theUrl = 'your URL';
    window.location.href = theUrl+"date="changedDate
    });
```

Else use, `on('change.dp', ..)` event like this,

```
this.$calendar
      .datepicker({
        options...
      }).on('change.dp', function() {
           var changedDate = this.$calendar.val();
           //alert("value of date is "+ x);
        var theUrl = 'your URL';
        window.location.href = theUrl+"date="changedDate
        });
```

Alternatively have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507671/bootstrap-datepicker-change-date-event-doesnt-fire-up-when-manually-editing-date) too.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's too late, but I have same problem and come up with this solution,
while setting options for Bootstrap Date Paginator keep track of onSelectedDateChanged function and assign the date value to a variable and send that variable to location.href.

```
            <script>
            var currDate = new Date();
            var options = {
                           selectedDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                           selectedDate: moment(currDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
                           onSelectedDateChanged: function (event, date) {
                                     var dateSelected = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
                                     location.href = '/ServletName?timestamp='+currDate .getTime() + "&date=" + dateSelected ;
                               },
                           };

             $('#paginator').datepaginator(options);

         </script>
         <body>
                <div id="paginator"></div>
         </body>
```