# jQuery UI DatePicker does not set the value of TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've added `jQueryUI DatePicker` on `HtmlTextBoxFor` in my MVC application. Below is my code. Now when I debug, The date shows `01/01/2001 12:00:00` in the `create` event instead of the date selected.

```
<!-- JoinDate -->
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JoinDate, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JoinDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "datepicker" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JoinDate)
</div>
```

```
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: You 've referenced jQuery-ui twice, you need to remove either one of the reference. I suggest remove `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>`

Comment: Still getting value `01/01/...`

Comment: What if you declare it like: `$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({defaultDate: ''});
});`

Comment: No it does not help.

Comment: What is the value of `JoinDate` when you pass the model to the view?

Comment: It would be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507671/bootstrap-datepicker-change-date-event-doesnt-fire-up-when-manually-editing-date

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution to this. I added an `input` and assign it `jQueryUI datepicker`. Now `onSelect` event, it just set the value to the `TextBoxfor`. See the code below.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```
<script>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    constrainInput: true,
    defaultDate: new Date(1975, 1 - 1, 1),
    yearRange: "2000:2025",
    onSelect: function () {
        alert($('#datepicker').val());
        $('#joindate').val($('#datepicker').val());
    }
});
</script>

<!-- JoinDate -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JoinDate, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                <input type="text" id="datepicker" onchange="onDateChange()"/>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JoinDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id="joindate" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JoinDate)
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `defaultDate:` - If the value of property `JoinDate` is set in the controller before you pass the model to the view, then that value will be displayed.

Comment: Actually this controller is to create. When I use it in View, I would not need `datepicker`.

Comment: That makes no sense. Why are you asking a question about something that's not needed? And why are you using `new { id="joindate" }` - the `id` is already `id="JoinDate"`

Comment: Thanks for the second advice. I actually did not know that. For the first thing you said, I know people here don't ask anything that is not needed. I need to implement datepicker for Create controller. In View details, I just show the date in Textboxfor.  No need to change it in View.